# Installing vowpalwabbit through pip gives error "target pattern contains no % ... recipe for target failed"

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, pip, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to install the vowpalwabbit library in a Python3.7 virtual environment. I get the following output when I try to install the library using pip (I get the same error when not using the virtual environment too so I don't think the issue is with the virtual environment) :

```
(vow) sanit@sanit-X:~/Documents/Work/ConBan$ pip install vowpalwabbit
Collecting vowpalwabbit
  Using cached vowpalwabbit-8.8.0.tar.gz (3.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: vowpalwabbit
    Running setup.py install for vowpalwabbit ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/sanit/Documents/Work/ConBan/vow/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-5hyyiq95/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sanit/Documents/Work/ConBan/vow/include/site/python3.7/vowpalwabbit
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit/
    Complete output (178 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/vowpalwabbit
    copying python/vowpalwabbit/pyvw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/vowpalwabbit
    copying python/vowpalwabbit/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/vowpalwabbit
    copying python/vowpalwabbit/sklearn_vw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/vowpalwabbit
    running egg_info
    writing python/vowpalwabbit.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to python/vowpalwabbit.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to python/vowpalwabbit.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'python/vowpalwabbit.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'python/*.dll' under directory 'python/bin'
    warning: no files found matching 'python/packages.config' under directory 'python/windows*'
    warning: no files found matching 'python/*.vcxproj*' under directory 'python/windows*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.o' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.exe' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vowpalwabbit/.nuget'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vowpalwabbit/slim'
    writing manifest file 'python/vowpalwabbit.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying python/vowpalwabbit/conda_install.sh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/vowpalwabbit
    running build_ext
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPY_VERSION=3.7 -DBUILD_PYTHON=On -DBUILD_TESTS=Off -DWARNINGS=Off -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=ON -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7 /tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit
    -- VowpalWabbit Version: 8.8.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Number of processors: 8
    -- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
    -- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
    -- Looking for pthread_create
    -- Looking for pthread_create - not found
    -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
    -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
    -- Found Threads: TRUE
    -- Boost version: 1.58.0
    -- Found the following Boost libraries:
    --   program_options
    --   system
    --   thread
    --   unit_test_framework
    --   chrono
    --   date_time
    --   atomic
    -- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8")
    -- help2man not found, please install it to generate manpages
    -- Python 3.7 will be used for VowpalWabbit Python bindings
    -- Found PythonInterp: /home/sanit/Documents/Work/ConBan/vow/bin/python3.7 (found suitable version "3.7.6", minimum required is "3.7")
    -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so (found suitable version "3.7.6", minimum required is "3.7")
    -- Boost version: 1.58.0
    -- Found the following Boost libraries:
    --   system
    --   python3
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    cmake --build . --config Release -- -j8 pylibvw
    Scanning dependencies of target allreduce
    [  1%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/allreduce.dir/vw_exception.cc.o
    [  1%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/allreduce.dir/allreduce_threads.cc.o
    [  2%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/allreduce.dir/allreduce_sockets.cc.o
    [  3%] Linking CXX static library liballreduce.a
    [  3%] Built target allreduce
    Scanning dependencies of target vw
    [  7%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/audit_regressor.cc.o
    [  7%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/action_score.cc.o
    [  6%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/autolink.cc.o
    [  7%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/active_cover.cc.o
    [  8%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/baseline.cc.o
    [ 10%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/accumulate.cc.o
    [ 11%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/active.cc.o
    [ 12%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/best_constant.cc.o
    [ 12%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/bfgs.cc.o
    [ 13%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/binary.cc.o
    [ 15%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/boosting.cc.o
    [ 16%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/bs.cc.o
    [ 17%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_adf.cc.o
    [ 17%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cache.cc.o
    [ 18%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_explore_adf_cover.cc.o
    [ 20%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_algs.cc.o
    [ 21%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_explore_adf_bag.cc.o
    [ 21%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_explore_adf_first.cc.o
    [ 22%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_explore_adf_greedy.cc.o
    [ 23%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_explore_adf_regcb.cc.o
    [ 25%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_explore_adf_softmax.cc.o
    [ 26%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_explore.cc.o
    [ 26%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb_sample.cc.o
    [ 27%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cb.cc.o
    [ 28%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cbify.cc.o
    [ 30%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/ccb_label.cc.o
    [ 30%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/classweight.cc.o
    [ 31%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/comp_io.cc.o
    [ 32%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/conditional_contextual_bandit.cc.o
    [ 33%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/confidence.cc.o
    [ 35%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cost_sensitive.cc.o
    [ 35%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/cs_active.cc.o
    [ 36%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/csoaa.cc.o
    [ 37%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/ect.cc.o
    [ 38%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/example.cc.o
    [ 40%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/explore_eval.cc.o
    [ 40%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/ftrl.cc.o
    [ 41%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/gd_mf.cc.o
    [ 42%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/gd.cc.o
    [ 43%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/gen_cs_example.cc.o
    [ 43%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/global_data.cc.o
    [ 45%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/interact.cc.o
    [ 46%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/interactions.cc.o
    [ 47%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/io_buf.cc.o
    [ 48%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/kernel_svm.cc.o
    [ 48%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/label_dictionary.cc.o
    [ 50%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/lda_core.cc.o
    [ 51%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/learner.cc.o
    [ 52%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/log_multi.cc.o
    [ 52%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/loss_functions.cc.o
    [ 53%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/lrq.cc.o
    [ 55%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/lrqfa.cc.o
    [ 56%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/marginal.cc.o
    [ 57%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/memory_tree.cc.o
    [ 57%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/mf.cc.o
    [ 58%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/multiclass.cc.o
    [ 60%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/multilabel_oaa.cc.o
    [ 61%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/multilabel.cc.o
    [ 61%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/mwt.cc.o
    [ 62%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/network.cc.o
    [ 63%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/nn.cc.o
    [ 65%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/no_label.cc.o
    [ 66%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/noop.cc.o
    [ 66%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/oaa.cc.o
    [ 67%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/OjaNewton.cc.o
    [ 68%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/options_boost_po.cc.o
    [ 70%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/options_serializer_boost_po.cc.o
    [ 71%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/parse_args.cc.o
    [ 71%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/parse_example.cc.o
    [ 72%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/parse_primitives.cc.o
    [ 73%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/parse_regressor.cc.o
    [ 75%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/parser.cc.o
    [ 75%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/print.cc.o
    [ 76%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/rand48.cc.o
    [ 77%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/recall_tree.cc.o
    [ 78%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/scorer.cc.o
    [ 80%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/search_dep_parser.cc.o
    [ 80%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/search_entityrelationtask.cc.o
    [ 81%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/search_graph.cc.o
    [ 82%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/search_hooktask.cc.o
    [ 83%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/search_meta.cc.o
    [ 83%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/search_multiclasstask.cc.o
    [ 85%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/search_sequencetask.cc.o
    [ 86%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/search.cc.o
    [ 87%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/sender.cc.o
    [ 88%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/shared_feature_merger.cc.o
    [ 88%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/simple_label.cc.o
    [ 90%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/stagewise_poly.cc.o
    [ 91%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/svrg.cc.o
    [ 92%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/topk.cc.o
    [ 92%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/unique_sort.cc.o
    [ 93%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/version.cc.o
    [ 95%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/vw_exception.cc.o
    [ 96%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/vw_validate.cc.o
    [ 97%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/warm_cb.cc.o
    [ 97%] Linking CXX static library libvw.a
    [ 97%] Built target vw
    python/CMakeFiles/pylibvw.dir/build.make:95: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:708: recipe for target 'python/CMakeFiles/pylibvw.dir/all' failed
    make[2]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/pylibvw.dir/all] Error 2
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:720: recipe for target 'python/CMakeFiles/pylibvw.dir/rule' failed
    make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/pylibvw.dir/rule] Error 2
    Makefile:344: recipe for target 'pylibvw' failed
    make: *** [pylibvw] Error 2
    error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/sanit/Documents/Work/ConBan/vow/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-5hyyiq95/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sanit/Documents/Work/ConBan/vow/include/site/python3.7/vowpalwabbit Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried googling this but have only found some stuff regarding cmake and none regarding pip. What can I do to fix this?
Thanks!

ETA:
I tried to install the library on python3.6 instead. It gives the exact same error.

ETA2:

I ran the installation again to get the temp file. The error occurred on line 84 of the build.make file now. Line 84 is `../lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pylibvw.so: Boost::python3-NOTFOUND`

But earlier in the configuration log, there's another line proclaiming that boost has been found.

ETA3:

This issue hasn't been resolved yet but I was able to install the library for Python2 without any issues, so I am using that for now.

Comment: What OS and version is this? What CMake version do you have installed?

Comment: @jackgerrits I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I had CMake 3.5.1 installed and this error came up so I upgraded to 3.16.4 but the error still persists.

Comment: Error message refers to the specific line: `python/CMakeFiles/pylibvw.dir/build.make:95`. This is a path relative to the build directory of CMake project: `/tmp/pip-install-bcdwz4bz/vowpalwabbit/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7`. Please, add content of the erroneous line into the question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I ran the installation again to get the temp file. The error occurred on line 84 now. Line 84 is ../lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pylibvw.so: Boost::python3-NOTFOUND

Comment: `Boost::python3-NOTFOUND` means that Python library for Boost hasn't been found by CMake. But you have lines `Found the following Boost libraries:` .. `python3` in the configuration log. My **guess** is that Python library for Boost has been found *partially*: e.g., the library has been found for `Debug` configuration, but has not been found for `Release` configuration. I don't know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Tsyvarev How do I proceed with this then? Is there someone I can ask about this? Should I post a new question? Or, can I solve this by simply uninstalling and reinstalling stuff?

Comment: "I don't know" means only that I cannot help more with that problem. But others could possibly do. Just wait. And do not forget to add the erroneous line into the **question post**: on Stack Overflow *comments* are temporary things, and all important information should be contained in the *question post* itself.

Comment: Just making sure: did you install boost-python? `sudo apt install libboost-python-dev` 

There is also a known issue for Ubuntu 16.04 - can you please follow the instructions for Ubuntu 16.04 and Python3 [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/python#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue for Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3. From the [VowpalWabbit wiki Python page](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Python#linux-1):

> For python3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: Ubuntu 16.04 defaults to an old,
>   custom-built version of boost. As such, the boost_python library names
>   do not follow the standard naming convention adopted by offical boost
>   releases for the boost_python libraries. You may need to manually
>   create the relevant symlinks in this case. Example commands for python
>   3.5 follows:
>
> ```
> $ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
> $ sudo ln -s libboost_python-py35.so libboost_python3.s
> $ sudo ln -s libboost_python-py35.a libboost_python3.a
> ```

Comment: I checked again, libboost-python-dev is installed in my computer. I created the relevant symlinks for python3.5 and tried installing vowpalwabbit for it but I still got the same error.

Comment: @Sanit I thought you were using Python 3.7? The above commands are simply an *example*, and you should adapt them to align with **your specific* Python installation.

Comment: @squareskittles Yes, I was using Python 3.7 earlier but I couldn't find the libboost files relevant to that version. I could find the files for Python 3.5 easily. So, I just tried the above commands to see if they would fix things for Python 3.5 and they did not.